# How can Apache FOP find Font with relative path in resources/fonts?

Tags: java, relative-path, apache-fop

This is where my font is located `resources/fonts/Arial.ttf`

This is how I am referencing my relative path:

```
FontUris fontUris = new FontUris(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
.getResource("fonts/Arial.ttf").toURI(), null);

fopFactoryBuilder.getFontManager().setResourceResolver(
ResourceResolverFactory.createDefaultInternalResourceResolver(fontUris.getEmbed()));

confInputStream = FopGenerator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fopconf.xconf");

fopFactoryBuilder.setConfiguration(new DefaultConfigurationBuilder().build(confInputStream));
```

This is the fopconf.xconf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fop>
<strict-validation>false</strict-validation>
<base>.</base>
<font-base>./</font-base>
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
       <fonts>
        <font kerning="yes" embed-url="Arial.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
             <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="400"/>
        </font>
       </fonts>
    </renderer>
  </renderers>
</fop>
```

While debugging the embedded url in fontUris is exactly the path to the font:

```
/Users/midi/IdeaProjects/MyProject/forms/target/classes/fonts/Arial.ttf
```

But still when printing the document I'm getting the following warning:

```
org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Arial,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".
```

Comment: You said, your font is in `resources/fonts/Arial.ttf`. But then you say what is your fontUris and that is different. I also use Arial. But I don't have to set the font manager. I just made the embed-url relative. You can try this. In my case I have embed-url="../fonts/arial.ttf" and it works. But I use the command line version of fop. That behaves probably differently.

Comment: By default, build tools like Maven, Gradle, or common Java practice will copy all files from "src/main/resources" to the root of "target/classes" or "build/classes". So, when we try to read a file from "src/main/resources", we read the file from the root of the project classpath.